# select one menu doesn't fill the value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 4.0.7 .I used selectonemenu,this menu showed the variables however value was null in Bean.Is there any configuration can i do?

Here is part of xhtml code;

```
<h:outputText value="#{etiketler.kullaniciTipi} : " />
<p:selectOneMenu id="kullaniciTipi" style="width:200px" value="#{kullaniciIslemleriBean.userRole}" >
<f:selectItems  value="#{enumBean.kullaniciTipiValues}" var="kullaniciTipi" 
itemLabel="#{kullaniciTipi.name}" itemValue="#{kullaniciTipi}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

here is part of kullaniciIslemleriBean code;

```
private EnumBase.KullaniciTipi userRole;
 public void Kaydet() {
  if (userRole == null) {
   System.out.println("null value");
   return;
   }
...

}

public EnumBase.KullaniciTipi getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(EnumBase.KullaniciTipi userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
```

Comment: You should REALLY use english naming convention in your code... also, what is Kaydet? I don't see it used anywhere in your xhtml. Please post more context (bigger part of your xhtml and bean).

Answer (score 0):

> Try storing it as String, it will work fine. If you want to store it
>   as Enum then try converter

```
<h:outputText value="#{etiketler.kullaniciTipi} : " />
<p:selectOneMenu id="kullaniciTipi" style="width:200px" value="#{kullaniciIslemleriBean.userRole}" >
<f:selectItems  value="#{enumBean.kullaniciTipiValues}" var="kullaniciTipi" 
itemLabel="#{kullaniciTipi.name}" itemValue="#{kullaniciTipi.name}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

private String userRole;
 public void Kaydet() {
  if (userRole == null) {
   System.out.println("null value");
   return;
   }
...

}

public String getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
```